# Incorrect input string format in Calculator

Tags: c#, input, string-formatting

I am having a very annoying issue that I have been looking everywhere to find but none of them make sense to me. I have only recently started C# so if its a silly mistake, well sorry.

Ive built a calculator and I can successfully make it but I want it to show the operations as the user clicks them. For example when the user clicks on the 6 button of course it shows 6 in the textfield **then** when he presses the plus(+) button, it should display [6 + ] and then he presses 5 for example and it looks like this in the textfield [6 + 5].

Now here's my error. I can make all the above work but when i click the equals(=) button, I get an error. It says

> "Input string was not in correct format."

It says the error is on this line of code:

```
 decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(LCD.Tag) +
 Convert.ToDecimal(LCD.Text);
```

Heres my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Window : Form
    {

        bool pluss = false;
        bool minuss = false;
        bool multiplyy = false;
        bool dividee = false;

        public Window()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LCD.Text = "";
        }

        private void dec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (LCD.Text.Contains("."))
            {
                return;
            }
            else {
                LCD.Text = LCD.Text + ".";
            }
        }

        private void zero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LCD.Text = LCD.Text + "0";
        }

        private void one_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LCD.Text = LCD.Text + "1";
        }

        private void two_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LCD.Text = LCD.Text + "2";
        }

        private void three_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LCD.Text = LCD.Text + "3";
        }

        private void four_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LCD.Text = LCD.Text + "4";
        }

        private void five_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LCD.Text = LCD.Text + "5";
        }

        private void six_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LCD.Text = LCD.Text + "6";
        }

        private void seven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LCD.Text = LCD.Text + "7";
        }

        private void eight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LCD.Text = LCD.Text + "8";
        }

        private void nine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LCD.Text = LCD.Text + "9";
        }

        private void plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (LCD.Text == "")
            {
                return;
            }else{
                pluss = true;
                LCD.Tag = LCD.Text;
                LCD.Text = LCD.Text + " + ";
            }
        }

        private void equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(LCD.Tag) + Convert.ToDecimal(LCD.Text);
            LCD.Text = total.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I am awaiting someone's response and I'll be so greatful if I get a fix.
Thanks.

Comment: if the LCD.Text contains LCD.Text + " + ".  it will fail!

Comment: @Ed S. Convert.ToDecimal("4 + 2") will fail

Comment: @c0deNinja: Nope, sure doesn't.  Perhaps you should test it out.  Now, a single `+` without a valid number to be found, or multiple numbers (i.e., `"4 + 2"`) will of course fail.

Comment: @c0deNinja: Yes, that will fail :D.  I'm sure this is what the OP is seeing, just trying to nudge him/her into debugging their own code.

Comment: What in the world???

What you are trying to do will quickly prove to be more trouble than it is worth.  You have to break down the string in LCD.Text and code many combinations of equations to make this work.  It's going to quickly become a lot of work.  You should keep it simple and show one number at a time, and never show the operators in the textbox. This will make things much more manageable.  If you are a C# newb, crawl before you walk.  Don't start off with bad requirements.  Wanting to show the whole equation in nice, but it adds much more work than you prob can handle at this point.

Answer (score 4):

When your program crashes:

1. Break into the debugger.
2. Inspect the value of `LCD.Tag` and `LCD.Text`.
3. Viola, you will surely notice something awry in the format.

I realize this is a practice project, but this kind of string manipulation back and forth is not the best way to build a calculator.  Better to separate the display from the data structures used to contain expression trees and values (i.e., the data structures used to do the actual calculation).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert a string that contains the "+" symbol to decimal format.

Place some breakpoints in your application and inspect where it crashes, the value will probably not be what you expect it to be.

Comment: You are assuming something like `"0.12+"` will fail to parse, but it will not.

Comment: @EdS: I was referring to something more along the lines of: `1 + 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what you're giving to `Convert.ToDecimal` to convert (`LCD.Text`). It expects a number in string format but you're passing it something like "`1 + 2`" which is not.  You must evaluate the expression yourself.

Comment: Okay im here trying to fix it but I'm stil not quite sure how.

Comment: What you're looking for is an expression evaluator.  Something that will take your 1 + 2 and return the result 3.  You can write your own or find a library online.  See here for a tutorial.  http://www.strchr.com/expression_evaluator